# Is there an R function to move data after a certain string?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to move data to a new column after certain points in the data. My data is spread across multiple data frames that only have some elements in common, so I would like to be able to make a loop to clean the data sets. I am looking for a function that after the first time there is certain text, for example "Total", in a row all the data below that moves to a new columns.

| first | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 |  |
| One | 1 |  |
| Total | 2 |  |
| Two | 2 |  |
| Two | 2 |  |
| Total | 2 |  |

I want my data to look similar to this below, but due to the variability of the data I am having trouble finding a solution that can be reproduced easily.

| left | center | right | fourth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | Two | 2 |
| One | 1 | Two | 2 |
| Total | 1 | Total | 2 |

Comment: please add a reproducible example to explain your requirement

Comment: Please consider create a minimal reproducible example so you can get more answers quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi thanks for edit. please also include desired output whether calculated/written manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal opinion `cbind`ing data on wider side will be too cumbersome, if the rows are too much.  Still you can divide the data into separate groups like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "first  second
One 1   
One 1   
Total   2   
Two 2   
Two 2   
Total   2", header = T)


df$dummy = rev(cumsum(rev(df$first == "Total")))
df
> df
  first second dummy
1   One      1     2
2   One      1     2
3 Total      2     2
4   Two      2     1
5   Two      2     1
6 Total      2     1
```

You may notice that your data is divided into two groups.  You may still `cbind()` or `bind_cols()` if you want, easily

```
df %>% group_split(d = rev(cumsum(rev(first == "Total")))) %>% bind_cols()

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  first...1 second...2 d...3 first...4 second...5 d...6
  <chr>          <int> <int> <chr>          <int> <int>
1 Two                2     1 One                1     2
2 Two                2     1 One                1     2
3 Total              2     1 Total              2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another try

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

data <- structure(list(first = c("One", "One", "Total", "Two", "Two", 
  "Total"), second = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame")

new_data <- data %>%
  # create group using first == "Total"
  mutate(total_group = cumsum(first == "Total")) %>%
  mutate(total_group = if_else(first == "Total", total_group - 1L, total_group)) %>%
  # split df into multiple df and bind cols
  group_split(total_group, .keep = FALSE) %>%
  bind_cols()
#> New names:
#> * first -> first...1
#> * second -> second...2
#> * first -> first...3
#> * second -> second...4

new_data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   first...1 second...2 first...3 second...4
#>   <chr>          <int> <chr>          <int>
#> 1 One                1 Two                2
#> 2 One                1 Two                2
#> 3 Total              2 Total              2

# if you only have two group this could work - otherwise need some more 
# work on the approach. Hope this provide you enough hint to develop further
names(new_data) <- c("left", "center", "right", "fourth")
new_data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   left  center right fourth
#>   <chr>  <int> <chr>  <int>
#> 1 One        1 Two        2
#> 2 One        1 Two        2
#> 3 Total      2 Total      2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>